# C++: Deleting a node in BST, either gets a seg fault or duplicates node

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

So I've done quite a bit of searching around, but many of the people who have deletion problems have completely different BST implementations than I do. On this assignment, we were given a BST class with the field nodeContent, and pointers to root, leftChild, and rightChild. This week out assignment was to create a function that deletes a specified node in the tree, and then we should be able to traverse the tree to verify that the node is gone. I thought I was making good process but when I test my code, it either returns that the node has indeed been removed, but the node that I copied from, has been duplicated. Alternately, when I try to delete a note with two children, I get a segmentation fault. I am new to posting on SO, so if I did this incorrectly, I apologize. I've just been racking my brain trying to see where I went wrong! Thanks in advance. Oh yeah, and I apologize for the crazy amount of comments.. I add a lot of comments when I get stuck to try and talk myself though the steps.

```
            /*
            void BST::deleteNode(int el)
            Input: An integer that is to be deleted from the tree
            Output: Nothing
            Side Effect: Single node deleted and tree reordered
            */
            void BST::deleteNode(int el)
            {
              BSTNode *temp;
              BSTNode *prev;
              BSTNode *node = Root;

              while (node -> nodeContent != el && node != NULL) // start the search
              {
                // if the search is less than 
                if(el < node -> nodeContent)
                {
                  node = node -> leftChild;
                }
                else if (el > node -> nodeContent)
                {
                  node = node -> rightChild;
                }

                if (node == NULL)
                {
                  std::cout << "That item cannot be deleted, "
                              "because it doesn't exist" << std::endl;
                  return;
                }
              }
              // ok, so we found the node

              // this is if node has two children
              if (node -> leftChild != NULL && node -> rightChild != NULL)
              {
                // first, set temp to rightmost node in left subtree
                temp = node -> leftChild;
                while (temp -> rightChild != NULL)
                {
                  // set prev to the node above node (bad name resolution, I know..)
                  prev = temp;
                  temp = temp -> rightChild;
                }
                // now we have our node, temp, and prev set.
                // time to do some copying
                // first step: set prev's rightChild to NULL
                prev -> rightChild = NULL;
                // ok. now we need to check if temp has a left child
                if (temp -> leftChild != NULL)
                {
                  //if it does, set it to prev's rightChild
                  prev -> rightChild = temp -> leftChild;
                }
                // done. Now set nodes content to temps content
                node -> nodeContent = temp -> nodeContent;
                // good work. now delete temp
                delete temp;
                temp = NULL;
              }
              // this one is for deleting a node without a right child
              if (node -> rightChild == NULL && node -> leftChild != NULL)
              {
                // using temp this time as the leftChild of the node to be deleted
                temp = node -> leftChild;
                // copy the content from child to node's content
                node -> nodeContent = temp -> nodeContent;
                // george r.r. martin the heck out of temp, for his watch has ended
                delete temp;
                temp = NULL;
              }
              // now, if (soon-to-be) deleted node only has a right child
              if (node -> leftChild == NULL && node -> rightChild != NULL)
              {
                // set temp to be nodes rightChild
                temp = node -> rightChild;
                // copy content from temp to to node
                node -> nodeContent = temp -> nodeContent;
                // delete temp
                delete temp;
                temp = NULL;
              }
              // the last one should be the easiest, if the node has no children
              if (node -> leftChild == NULL && node -> rightChild == NULL)
              {
                delete node;
              } 
            }
```

Comment: What did you observe running your code in the debugger? Are you deleting nodes twice by chance? Did you implement copy and assignment operators correctly?

Comment: A [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful, but the first thing I notice is that `while (node -> nodeContent != el && node != NULL)` can cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are using three `if` statements and not returning from any of the blocks. So, imagine that your first `if` statement was satisfied and that node had just one right child. This child got deleted.

Now, the code goes to the second `if` statement and that in turn is true! It then executes the second `if` block.

I hope this leads you to the answer.
Also, to find where the segmentation fault occurred exactly [GDB](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/review/gdb.html). It is an essential tool if you are coding in C++.

Comment: Good point.. I'm embarrassed that I missed that! thank you for the help!

Comment: I only had a second to check it before class started, but I added return; right after the delete commands in hopes It would fix it.. But no luck unfortunately.. I'll have to keep messing with it but that was a good start I think

Comment: I've never used GDB before but it seems very helpful. I'll try it soon as I get home. Thanks!